# Possible in JDBC / MySQL to retrieve updated rows?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate()
```

Returns the number of rows updated.  To my research so far it's not possible to do an update-query in which you would retrieve the updated rows, but this seems like such a basic feature that I'm clearly missing something.  How to accomplish this?

Comment: I think it's simply not possible. My understanding is you are looking for something similar as PostgreSQL's `UPDATE ... RETURNING` which does exactly that. But to my knowledge MySQL does not have such a feature.

Comment: We tried to overcome this problem for logging and were not able to find anything like this, neither DB triggers nor JDBC driver helped us. Fortunately most of our update queries were ran with either primary or foreign key in "where" clause. This way we were able to use "general sql parser" to retrieve the column names and values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you can post this as answer and I'll accept.  Knowing the PostgreSQL equivalent was enough for me to Google this and find many complaints that this feature does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per first comment on question this is simply not possible in MySQL.  PostgreSQL supports `UPDATE...RETURNING` as this feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you use executeQuery instead of executeUpdate, you get a resultset back.

<s>Then, change your stored procedure to be a function, and return the changed rows in a select at the end of the function. AFAIK, you cannot return data from a procedure in MySQL (as opposed to e.g. Microsoft SQL server).</s>

EDIT: The suggestion struck out above is not possible. The JDBC specification does not allow updates in query statements (see the answer for this one: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=692).

BUT, if you know the WHERE clause of the rows you are about to update, you can always select them first, to get the primary keys, perform the update, and then perform a select on them afterwards. Then you get the changed rows.

Comment: 24112 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR  - Fatal error: 
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: Sorry, looks like you're right. This is forbidden in the JDBC spec (see edited answer above).

Comment: You get more rows than the changed rows, because the values in the "where" clause are changed to other existing values in the table.

Comment: I don't understand excactly what you mean, but if you, before you update the rows, perform a select with the exact same where statement, then save away (in an array of whatever) the IDs of those rows, perform the update, and then select the rows with the previously selected row ids (if you need the latest version of those rows after the update from the database). Maybe it would be easier if you gave a SQL example.

Comment: That creates a race condition.  I haven't thus far been able to work out the right way to do this using transactions and probably multiple JDBC queries, but it may be a hard problem to do that well.

Comment: I really can't comment any more on this without getting an example. I don't see how performing a select could create a race condition...

Comment: Machine 1 does a "select" and gets users 1,2,3.  Before machine 1 updates, machine 2 does the same select and gets users 1,2,3.  Now machine 1 updates to say it has them, and machine 2 does, and they erroneously both have the user.  Race condition between machine 1 update and machine 2 select.

Comment: This is what transactions are made for. Use TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE, and you won't end up in the situation you describe. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: I imagine this is possible with transactions but I also know it's still a bit less trivial than that - it's also a requirement that this SQL pair of queries should not be able to lock any operation on the table from reads/writes, just other instances of the same pair of queries running on different machines.  I've wondered if it would need to be a stored function that transactions against any other calls to the same function.

Answer (score -1):

when you fire  preparedStatement.executeUpdate() you already have the row identifiers using which you can uniquely identify the rows you want updated- you need to use the same identifiers to do a query and fetch the updated rows. you can not accomplish update and retrieval in one shot using JDBC apis.

Comment: This is false because the update is not reversible.  E.g., I could be updating a bunch of football players from "rookie" to "veteran" and then need the ones just updated to veteran, but of course there are many more veterans I am *not* interested in.