# get list of inserted or modified records (rows) using spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: sql, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc

If I am inserting 5 (or n) rows (list of rows) into a table then how to get these record from the table after insertion using JdbcTemplate. I am able to get count of modified rows but not able to get list of modified record(rows). Please Help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible in JDBC / MySQL to retrieve updated rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850139/possible-in-jdbc-mysql-to-retrieve-updated-rows)

Comment: This is not possible